# C++ std::vector in class, function crash on returning value and size growing in foreach

Tags: c++, templates, stl, stdvector

I'm writing a content management system to avoid duplicates of the same loaded texture in my game engine. The following is the function for retrieving content from the previously loaded in objects or to load in a new object if none is available.

```
    template <class T>
    T* GetContent(const char* path) {
        // Check if it already exists, if yes return it
        for (ContentEntry& entry : m_ContentList) {
            // Same Type?
            if (strcmp(entry.Type, T::GetType()) == 0)
                // Same Path?
                if (strcmp(entry.C->GetPath(), path) == 0)
                    return (T*)entry.C;
        }

        // Since it doesn't exist, create it
        ContentEntry contentEntry (
            T::GetType(),
            (Content*)new T(path));

        // Add it to the list
        m_ContentList.push_back(contentEntry);

        // And Return it
        return (T*)contentEntry.C;
    }
```

And this is the struct used to store content entries and the vector they're stored in.

```
    struct ContentEntry {
        const char* Type;
        Content* C;

        ContentEntry(const char* type, Content* c) :
            Type(type),
            C(c)
        { }
        ~ContentEntry() {
            delete C;
        }
    };

    std::vector<ContentEntry> m_ContentList;
```

Whenever this function tries to return the value, the app crashes. When I change contentEntry to a pointer (updating the code around it appropriately) it returns with no problem but I have to change the entire vector to point to ContentEntry pointers and then manually delete them which I would like to avoid if possible. How could I make this function work correctly?

Additionally, when using the pointer and stepping through the foreach loop, the vector seems to grow drastically for no clear reason, how can I stop this from happening?

**Edit:** For now fixed the crashing problem which I'll later refine, but the vector growing out of control is still there.

**Edit2:** The vector growing seems to just disappear after exiting the function so I'm just gonna mark something as answer.

Comment: What does `T::GetType()` return that you are freeing it with a `delete` call? Also you need to provide a copy constructor in your `ContentEntry` struct, otherwise only the `Type` and `C` pointers will be copied (not what they point to) which will result in trying to free the same memory twice (since pushing `ContentEntry` into the container results in a copy being made).

Comment: A `const char*` used to identify the content type (just realized that I definitely don't want to delete that)

Comment: How is that `const char*` allocated though?

Comment: Just a simple `GetType() { return "MyContentType"; }`

Comment: Ok, you really don't want to `delete` that then. And you need a copy constructor to make a deep copy of the `C` pointer.

Comment: I fixed the crash by deleting `C` somewhere else but the vector still grows to ridiculous sizes in the loop.

Comment: @LaylConway If you're remotely curious for why it fixed your problem to remove the `delete` it is most-likely because you were corrupting all sorts of things by running a `const char*` literal through `delete`. Note: this thing is *begging* for a `std::string` and proper [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), and I *strongly* advise reading more about that methodology.

Comment: The fact that I was deleting the `const char*` was a separate problem. Most of the app (including anything that extends `Content`) does use proper RAII but this class is supposed to make sure content doesn't get loaded in twice at different locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you are deleting something which looks like a string using `delete` rather than `delete[]`. Of course, this assumes that the string was allocated in the first place. Based on your comment you try to `delete` a string literal which causes undefined behavior at that point.

That said, please note that you are slicing your object when you insert it into the vector and, more importantly, you don't get a deep copy of the `ContentEntry` members (this type is lacking a copy constructor and probably an assignment operator). Thus, after inserting the `ContentEntry` into your `std::vector<ContentEntry>` the newly allocated object is gone. Another interesting bit is that you cast your `T*` to a `Content*`. The allocate object is `delete`d through a pointer to `Content`. Thus, either the cast is unnecessary (and hopefully your type `Content` has a `virtual` destructor) or things will start going bad at that point.

Comment: It seemed that the problem was that the end of the function caused `C` to be deconstructed simply by calling `~ContentEntry()`. Removing this delete fixed this and I'm now adding a proper delete to the deconstructor of the content manager instead. I do have a virtual deconstructor in Content.

Comment: For resource management you want the immediate owner of the resource take care of it. In your case, you probably don't need any destructor at all! Instead, use a `std::shared_ptr<Content>` and it will take care of proper resource management.

Comment: I'll look into moving my current code to using that but currently I'm still walking against the vector growing to huge sizes.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Since it doesn't exist, create it
    ContentEntry contentEntry (
        T::GetType(),
        (Content*)new T(path));

    // Add it to the list
    m_ContentList.push_back(contentEntry);

    // And Return it
    return (T*)contentEntry.C;
```

Your problem is in these three lines, in combination with `ContentEntry` not having a copy constructor (and copy assignment).

- in the first part you create a ContentEntry instance
- then you `push_back` a copy of that instance. this copy will point to the same T instance that the original `ContentEntry` pointed to.
- finally, the function exits, return the pointer-to-T. But at the exit, your local copy `contentEntry` is destroyed, which will `delete` the T-instance that the returned pointer points to.

In essence, you are not following the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) and are being punished for it.

Comment: I noticed this problem and resolved it, I'm now trying to resolve the vector growing problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need a copy constructor for ContentEntry.